# Is there an existing ANTLR or IRONY grammar for R?

Tags: r, antlr, grammar, irony, antlr4

Does anyone know if there is an existing existing ANTLR or IRONY grammar for R?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you already find the [Bison/Flex grammar](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/gram.y) in their SVN repository? If no one posts an ANTLR- or IRONY grammar, you could convert the Bison/Flex to either of those.

Comment: What do you intend to do with it?  Usually having just a parser doesn't buy you much; you typically need an AST, ways to traverse/analyze/modify the AST, etc.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - thanks! I'll certainly look into it!

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Apologies if my terms/understanding is incorrect, currently I'm using irony for a small DSL that converts to .net - based on that I've been asked to look at a way to interpret R

Comment: "a way to interpret R".  This implies you need an AST, means to walk over it program execution order (fun when hit a goto:where is the target in the tree?) and symbol tables (which can answer the "target" question I just asked) as a minimum.

Comment: @Jonno can I ask you if you ever resolved this matter? I need similar R parser but RCC site is not providing download link anymore. Can you share your experience please?

Comment: @Charles, please leave the tag `antlr4` there. The question does not mention that antlr4 cannot be used, and by adding this tag, it will be more easily found. Besides, Terence asked me to create a tag (since he didn't have enough rep to do so at that time) and this being the only question with the antlr4 tag, you removing it caused the "wiki/info" of this tag to be removed as well. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: @BartKiers, I will honor your request, however I still object to the tag needing to exist.  Tags are for questions, *not* for answers; there is nothing at all in the *question* that seems version-specific whatsoever.  Perhaps you can find some other questions that could also be tagged with `antlr4`?  This question alone seems like a bad starting point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've built an R grammar for the early access "Honey Badger" ANTLR v4 release, if you'd like to give it a look. See the [ANTLR v4 Examples page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Examples). Source for v4 is https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.  binary jar here: http://antlr.org/download/antlr-4.0ea-complete.jar  For R you want http://www.antlr.org/wiki/download/attachments/28049418/R.g4

Comment: I haven't *really* looked at v4 yet, but I will do so soon after seeing how ridiculously short that [R grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/playground/R.g4) is. Nice!

Comment: Some of the links no longer work - any chance of updated ones? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess a good place to look would be  [R to C Compiler (RCC) that was developed by John Garvin at Rice](http://www.hipersoft.rice.edu/rcc/)

Comment: Thanks Ira - I will check it out and mark your answer accepted if nothing else appears, many thanks.