# Lex- and YACC-like tools for R?

Tags: parsing, r, yacc, lex

Do such parsing tools exist for R? It does not have to be a lex / yacc compatible tool for my case.

(I'm an R newbie)

EDIT: I'm interested in implementing another language using R.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705564/is-there-an-existing-antlr-or-irony-grammar-for-r

Comment: that's about the grammar that defines R syntax. I think the poster wants to write a parser for some other language in R.

Comment: Exactly! If I am to implement another interpreter using R, do parsing tools exist?

Comment: [This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg93558.html) seems to suggest there is no such thing for R.

Comment: I had a quick search for "parse" on cran's list of packages and mostly there's code for parsing specific file formats and nothing general. It also matched 'sparse' :)

Comment: See the dparser package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no parser generator for R.

However, user created [packages in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf) (a.k.a. "extensions") can be written in Java, C or Fortran (and R, of course). So, you could use [Lex/Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) and [Bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/#bison) (in case of C) or [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (for Java) to create a lexer and parser for your language and use those in your R code.

Answer (score 9):

I developed a clone of python PLY named rly. You can find it in CRAN:

```
install.packages("rly")
```

Example of usage below:

```
library(rly)

TOKENS = c('NAME', 'NUMBER')
LITERALS = c('=','+','-','*','/', '(',')')

Lexer <- R6Class("Lexer",
  public = list(
    tokens = TOKENS,
    literals = LITERALS,
    t_NAME = '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*',
    t_NUMBER = function(re='\\d+', t) {
      t$value <- strtoi(t$value)
      return(t)
    },
    t_ignore = " \t",
    t_newline = function(re='\\n+', t) {
      t$lexer$lineno <- t$lexer$lineno + nchar(t$value)
      return(NULL)
    },
    t_error = function(t) {
      cat(sprintf("Illegal character '%s'", t$value[1]))
      t$lexer$skip(1)
      return(t)
    }
  )
)

Parser <- R6Class("Parser",
  public = list(
    tokens = TOKENS,
    literals = LITERALS,
    # Parsing rules
    precedence = list(c('left','+','-'),
                      c('left','*','/'),
                      c('right','UMINUS')),
    # dictionary of names
    names = new.env(hash=TRUE),
    p_statement_assign = function(doc='statement : NAME "=" expression', p) {
      self$names[[as.character(p$get(2))]] <- p$get(4)
    },
    p_statement_expr = function(doc='statement : expression', p) {
      cat(p$get(2))
      cat('\n')
    },
    p_expression_binop = function(doc="expression : expression '+' expression
                                                  | expression '-' expression
                                                  | expression '*' expression
                                                  | expression '/' expression", p) {
           if(p$get(3) == '+') p$set(1, p$get(2) + p$get(4))
      else if(p$get(3) == '-') p$set(1, p$get(2) - p$get(4))
      else if(p$get(3) == '*') p$set(1, p$get(2) * p$get(4))
      else if(p$get(3) == '/') p$set(1, p$get(2) / p$get(4))
    },
    p_expression_uminus = function(doc="expression : '-' expression %prec UMINUS", p) {
      p$set(1, -p$get(3))
    },
    p_expression_group = function(doc="expression : '(' expression ')'", p) {
      p$set(1, p$get(3))
    },
    p_expression_number = function(doc='expression : NUMBER', p) {
      p$set(1, p$get(2))
    },
    p_expression_name = function(doc='expression : NAME', p) {
      p$set(1, self$names[[as.character(p$get(2))]])
    },
    p_error = function(p) {
      if(is.null(p)) cat("Syntax error at EOF")
      else           cat(sprintf("Syntax error at '%s'", p$value))
    }
  )
)

lexer  <- rly::lex(Lexer)
parser <- rly::yacc(Parser)

while(TRUE) {
  cat('calc > ')
  s = readLines(file("stdin"), n=1)
  if(s == 'exit') break
  parser$parse(s, lexer)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [qmrparser](http://cran.r-project.org/package=qmrparser) package on CRAN.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there ARE YACC grammar files in R source code.
Check out these files,

`R-2.15.2\src\main\gram.y` 
`R-2.15.2\src\main\gramLatex.y`
`R-2.15.2\src\main\gramRd.y`

But I'm not sure if these files are built in the offical releases ......